# CakePHP getting data form an ID which is inside another table?

Tags: php, cakephp

Right, so my data returns in the following way,

```
  (int) 0 => array(
    'MODEL-XX' => array(
        //DATA HERE
        'xxs_id' => '11',
        'aas_id' => '44',
        'vvs_id' => '2'
    ),
    'xxs' => array(
        'id' => '11',
        'customername' => 'XX name here'
    ),
    'aas' => array(
        'id' => '44',
        'clientname' => 'aa name here',
        'xxs_id' => '11'
    ),
    'vvs' => array(
        'id' => '2',
        'start' => '1405296000',
        'end' => '1405814400',
        'users_id' => '1'
    )
```

This works fine, but I want to know how to link my users table to this model. So the details of each user for my VV model would become apart of the data. My MODEL-XX does not have any links with my users table so the place I need to call in the users details are held with my VV model.

I have been looking into this but have not been able to find a simple easy method for doing this?

I was thinking that this would be doable with my model, so I opened my my XX model and added the following within my '$belongsTo' section,

```
    'Users' => array(
        'className' => 'Users',
        'foreignKey' => 'vvs.users_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
```

So is there a easy method for linking data like this?

Please give me time, if I have not explained myself right or not enough data, please tell me and let me fix or explain better.

Thanks,

Comment: your user model is already connected to your VV model right? if you would set your recursive higher the user should pop up in the array. Even better is to use the Contain behaviour and contain the models you want into your find

Comment: @alexStallen - I knew I had forgotten to state something. I added, 'recursive' => 0 to the end of my find call, but that gave me the some results, then 'recursive' => +1, still with the same results without any users data added. And yes, my VV model links to my users table without any problems, querying that works.

Comment: you cannot set recursive +1 to my knowledge, it is just '1'. $this->MODEL-XX->recursive = 1; (or 2). You should really look into the contain behaviour

Comment: that might be where I am going wrong :) - thought it might be something like that, I try and let you know, thanks

Comment: I have just tried that, but again it did not work! - I have just come into contain behavior, I look into some more, thanks

Comment: following cakephp conventions users_id should be user_id

Comment: Please don't make up names in your code, that's highly distracting, use the actual model and column names!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either set your recusive higher:

```
$this->MODEL-XX->recursive = 1; //or 2
```

Or and this should be your prefered way to go, start using the containable behaviour:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html

In your appModel:

```
public $actsAs = array('Containable');
```

Then try this find:

```
$this->MODEL-XX->recursive = -1;

$data = $this-MODEL-XX>find(
        'all', array(
            'conditions' => $conditions,
            'contain' => array('xxs', 'aas', 'vvs', 'user')
        )
    );
```

I might be 'vvs.user' but I forgot what is used for deeper models

Comment: When I try this, I get Model "VV" is not associated with model "User". I have in the contain array vvs.User, if set to vvs.user, says 'Column not found' error. Now I have tried the link the User model to my VV model.

Comment: Many thanks - you put me on the right track :) - just for ref, I used vv.User which seems to work fine. I your comment about my users_id not being right and it should be user_id. I went though and change all my id's - I can never reminder whats is went to be what with with table names and models / keys. Many thanks